# Google customer review not showing at mobile page

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, survey, review

We use the survey opt-in module to display google customer review survey modal after finishing an order within our shop. It's the same smarty template with same data we use to print out the opt-in module script. When we take a look at the final page HTML/JS source both versions (desktop/mobile) have the same code and parameters.

At desktop the survey modal is loaded with all data and is displayed perfect. Mobile we do not get complete content to be shown within the modal box and the box stays hidden.

There is no script error shown in console. Everything comes with 400 response, no problems. Seems like google got an problem.

We did get in contact with google customer support, but they do not know what the problem is. They mentioned that mobile isn't supported that long so they don't know much about problems. And that they are no developers, so they can't give any support regarding technical issues.

This is what we have as opt-in module integration:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderOptIn"
        async defer>
</script>

<script>
    window.renderOptIn = setTimeout(function() {
        window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function() {
            window.gapi.surveyoptin.render(
                {
                    "merchant_id": "1234567",
                    "order_id": "104898746",
                    "email": "me@office.de",
                    "delivery_country": "DE",
                    "estimated_delivery_date": "2018-01-04",
                    "opt_in_style": "CENTER_DIALOG"
                });
        });
    }, 3000);
</script>
```

To give more understanding here the code from survey iframe on mobile. As you can see there's content missed and still hidden:

```
    <iframe frameborder="0" src="javascript:undefined" style="border: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; vertical-align: bottom; z-index: 2147483647; display: none; opacity: 0;"></iframe>
<div style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: none; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 2147483647; opacity: 0.5;"></div>
<div role="dialog" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(190, 190, 190); display: block; height: auto; overflow: visible; position: absolute; width: auto; z-index: 2147483647; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 4px 16px; visibility: hidden; left: 173px; top: 400px;">
    <div style="width: 10px; height: 10px;">
        <iframe ng-non-bindable="" frameborder="0" hspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" style="" tabindex="0" vspace="0" width="100%" id="I0_1515071001783" name="I0_1515071001783" src="https://www.google.com/shopping/customerreviews/optin?usegapi=1&amp;merchant_id=100922932&amp;hl=de&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fm.intra.bigtree.de%2Fcheckout%2Fcompleted.html%3Fid%3D104898746%26is%3Dok&amp;order_id=104898746&amp;usegapi=1&amp;jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.de.I7X0AzVouI4.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOE0nG8Zat0OwhsKEd_RMFwgVdQrA#id=I0_1515071001783&amp;_gfid=I0_1515071001783&amp;parent=http%3A%2F%2Fm.intra.bigtree.de&amp;pfname=&amp;rpctoken=31372899"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Perhaps anyone of you got an idea what to do. Opt-in module script integration is perfect, everything works as a charme at desktop.

Many thanks in advance for any help! :)

Comment: Any fix for this?

Comment: any fix you did to solve in mobile ? your help will be appriciated,

Answer (score 0):

Currently, google customer review badge is not available for mobile and tablet devices. More information regarding it can be found in the below link.

https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/9353531?hl=en&ref_topic=7105497